# JNI call fail on non static methods

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call a non static java method from C++ using the JNI on an Android project, but GetMethodID always return NULL.

this is my code:

```
void Java_com_kungfu_rabbit_KungFuRabbitActivity_nativeOnCreate(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    // this code works fine
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/kungfu/rabbit/KungFuRabbitActivity");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "foo", "()V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid);

    // this one fails:
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "foo2", "()V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj, mid);
}
```

I'm calling this native function from the class that extends Activity. foo is a public static void function, and foo2 is a public void function.
I can't understand why it fails...

Can anyone help me to understand?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible that your class lookup failed, or that you got the method signature wrong.  You should always check for errors when the JNI method may produce them.  What is the Java signature (in Java code) for the class/method in question?

Comment: I simplified the code for an easier comprehension. Of course I check the return values.
My java method's signature is 
public void foo()

I found another way to solve my problem:
I'm declaring a private static Activity in the Activity class, and set it to "this" in the onCreate method, so i can acces it from the static methods. it's not the most cleanest way to do it, but it works fine =)

Comment: From the signatures, it looks like the obj passed to your function is of com/kungfu/rabbit/KungFuRabbitActivity. Are you expecting a different object?